# Asymptotics for the divisor function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I am attempting to understand Tao's post of 23 September 2008 given [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound) concerning the divisor bound.

My troubles are when he uses the big-O notation in proving what he lists as bound (4)
$$
d(n) \leq \exp(O(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n})).
$$

First, after showing that
$$ d(n) \leq O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{\exp (1/\epsilon)} $$
he declares that
$$ O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{\exp(1/\epsilon)}=\exp(\exp(O(1/\epsilon))). $$
I do not know how to see this.
A tiny bit later he uses the above to write
$$
 d(n)\leq\exp(\exp(O(1/\epsilon)))n^\epsilon.
$$
We plug in $C/\log\log n$ and he declares that the second term in the right hand side dominates which can be seen by taking logarithms. I am also not seeing this. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at them in turn.

1. We want to show that $$ O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)^{\exp(1/\epsilon)}=\exp(\exp(O(1/\epsilon))). $$

   For ease of notation, I drop most $O(\cdot)$ constants. Then note that 
   $$ \left( \frac{1}{e} \right) ^{ \exp(1/\epsilon) } = e^{\log(1/\epsilon)\cdot \exp(1/\epsilon)}$$

   and in general, $\log x \cdot e^x = O(e^{x +\delta})$ for any $\delta > 0$. Thus
   $$ \left( \frac{1}{e} \right) ^{ \exp(1/\epsilon) } = e^{\log(1/\epsilon)\cdot \exp(1/\epsilon)} = \exp (\, \exp ( \, O (1/\epsilon )\, )\, )$$
2. Let's follow his suggestion. So set $\epsilon = C/\log\log n$ for some large $C$. Then we want to compare the growth of $\exp ( \exp ( O(1/\epsilon)))$ and $n^\epsilon$. I again drop most $O(\cdot)$ constants for ease. The first one:

   $$ \exp( \exp ( 1/\epsilon)) = \exp ( \exp ( \log \log n / C) ) = \exp \exp (\log (\log n)^{1/C} ) = \exp ( (\log n)^{1/C}).$$

   The second one stays:

   $$ n^{C/\log \log n}$$

   Now take logs. Then we compare

   $$ (\log n)^{1/C} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{C}{\log \log n} \log n$$

   Similar to the fact above, $\frac{x}{\log x} > x^{1 - \delta}$ for any $\delta > 0$. So for large $C$, the left side is like a small power (much less than $1$, say) of $\log n$ and the right side is like a larger power (pretty close to $1$) of $\log n$.

So that's one way of getting his two results. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: In " Then note that $ \left( \frac{1}{e} \right) ^{ \exp(1/\epsilon) } =\dots$", $\frac1e$ should be replaced by $\frac1\epsilon.$

Comment: By "in general, $\log x \cdot e^x = O(e^{x +\delta})$" you probably mean $\log x \cdot e^x = O(e^{x(1 +\delta)}).$

Comment: @AnneBauval i have a related post to this but since you've commented here I've decided to ask here. Why is it $O(e^{x(1+\delta)})$ and using it how does one get $(\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{exp(\frac{1}{\epsilon})} = exp(exp(O(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))$ is it not $exp(O(exp(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))$? I'm not seeing why we can take the exponential outside the "Big Oh"

Comment: @learningmathematics $\log x \cdot e^x = O(e^{x(1 +\delta)})$ because $\log x=O(e^{x\delta})$ (as $x\to+\infty$). And $e^{x(1 +\delta)}$ is not an $O(e^x)$ but it is an $e^{O(x)}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I am being slow. Could you elaborate on how you get those asymptotics - I'm fairly new to the notation and am not seeing it/