# Doubts about the asymptotic $\log(x)\exp(x) = O(e^{x+ \delta})$

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, asymptotics, real-numbers

I am trying to follow part 1 of the answer in this post: [Asymptotics for the divisor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488955/asymptotics-for-the-divisor-function)

They state that
$$\log(x)\exp(x) = O(e^{x + \delta}),\quad\forall\delta > 0.$$

I am not sure how to prove this though. I initially thought I could use the inverse property of log and exp.

Moreover, in the post the above asymptotic is applied to
$$\left(\frac1e\right)^{\exp\frac1\epsilon} = e^{\log\frac1\epsilon\exp\frac1\epsilon} = \exp\left(\exp\left(O\left(1/\epsilon\right)\right)\right).$$

But shouldn't it be
$$\left(\frac1e\right)^{\exp\frac1\epsilon} = e^{\log\frac1\epsilon\exp\frac1\epsilon} = \exp\left(O\left(\exp\left(1/\epsilon\right)\right)\right)?$$

Comment: But $\mathcal{O}(e^{x+\delta})=\mathcal{O}(e^x e^\delta)=\mathcal{O}(e^x)$ because $e^\delta$ is a constant in your context? What you say they say certainly isn't true.

Comment: @donaastor Thanks makes sense, it must be a constant in this situation. Could you explain the bottom part of my question? Thanks.

Comment: I absolutely have no idea what these equations represent, maybe because I don't understand how exactly you use the big O notation or what is $\epsilon$ and what limits are you observing. But I just saw that someone gave related comments just 22 hours ago to the answer which you linked in the question. I believe those comments can clarify the second part of your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a followup of [my comments of the answer to the post you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488955/asymptotics-for-the-divisor-function/489114?noredirect=1#comment9674693_489114).

- The $\frac1e$ of that answer, which you reproduce above, should be a $\frac1\epsilon.$
- For all $\delta>0,$ the $\log(x)\exp(x) = O(e^{x+ \delta})$ of that answer which caused you trouble is indeed obviously wrong (see donaastor's comment) but can be replaced by $\log(x)\exp(x)=O(e^{x(1+δ)})$ (as $x→+∞$), i.e. there exist two constants $A,B>0$ such that for every $x\ge B,$ $\log(x)\exp(x)\le Ae^{x(1+δ)}$ or equivalently: there exists $B$ such that $e^{-x\delta}\log(x)$ is bounded on $[B,+\infty)$ (in fact, any positive $B$ will do).
- This $\log(x)\exp(x)=O(e^{x(1+δ)})$ can be used to repair that answer: $Ae^{x(1+δ)}=e^{O(x)},$ i.e. there exist two constants $C\ge B$ and $D$ such that $Ae^{x(1+δ)}\le e^{xD}$ for all $x\ge C$: just take any $D>1+\delta$ and use that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}Ae^{x(1+\delta-D)}=0.$
- This estimate is (sufficient but) weaker than the one you suggest. It is true (though now useless) that $e^{x+\delta}=O(e^x)$ but (obviously) it is false that $e^{x(1+\delta)}=O(e^x)$, and even false that $\log(x)\exp(x)=O(e^x).$